# How auto-generate product and category url in magento

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

In magento 1 using indexes, we can generate `product and category url` but in magento 2 using indexes we cannot do this.

**I have so many products and category so how can i do this?**

Answer (score 0):

In magento2, It generates product and category urls based on given `url_key` on save event. If you will not provide any `url_key` it will use name value for generating url_key.
You can find url rewrites in `url_rewrite` table.
Url rewriting is well managed in Magento2 as compare to 1x versions. It is not dependent on indexing, it will be done whenever you will save the product.

Comment: ya right but i have 4k product so its take long time to save each product

Comment: it will ... you must be persisting them using csv or magento API ?  
It won't make any major difference in time and 4k is not that big amount for magento.